# Microsoft SQL Profiler with IdeaBlade

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, orm, devforce

I would like to ask you if is there any way to use Microsoft SQL Profiler to discover and improve performance with IdeaBlade ORM? 
Or maybe convert IdeaBlade queries to SQL and then throw to MS Profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run SQL Server Profiler tool while your ORM is running and querying your database, you will have all queries ran by your ORM.

You can then take some queries that appear to be long (watch for big values in Duration or Reads columns in profiler output) and you can take the SQL text query and run it in SQL Server MAnagement Studio.

If you can't change your ORM queries, the only way to improve the execution will be to run then in SQL Management Studio, study query plan and add missing indexes to your tables (note: studying query plans is a huge topic)